# Not able to reload a page after clicking on a button in php

Tags: php, html

I am not able to reload the php page after a certain button is pressed. That is there is no change until I reload the page by myself. The php script is:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

    if (($_SESSION['ShowGenerated'] == 'hidden'))
    {
        $class = 'hidden'; 
    }
    else if (($_SESSION['ShowGenerated'] == 'visible'))
    {
        $class = 'show'; 
    }   

?>

<html>
 <head>
....
<td><a href="Change.php" class="<?php echo $class; ?>" target="_blank"><button  id="pdf" name="Change" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="change-a"" aria-hidden="true"></i>Click Here</button></a></td>
...
```

On clicking "Click here" button, Change.php is called where `$_SESSION['ShowGenerated']` value is generated. How do I load the current page or a URL to show a change?

EDIT: Instead of reloading the whole page, can I only reload to check if the $_Session has changed in the html page?

Comment: you can use bootstrap btn classes also in <a> tag, which make the <a> tag looks like button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put  tag inside :

```
<button  id="pdf" name="Change" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="change-a"" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="Change.php" class="<?php echo $class; ?>" target="_blank">Click Here</a></button>
```

like this

Comment: Nothing changed. It actually messed up my button even more.